# MVC Ajax Partial View Not Cached: Unique Element ID

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, caching, partial-views, unique-id

I have a partial view which I load dynamically by calling a function similar to this as described [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)

```
$("#addItem").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: this.href,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
  });
   return false;
});
```

As described, the cache is set to false to maintain the uniqueness of the elements. How does the code above acheive this? That is, what is the new ID that is assigned to the elements? How can I control these Ids?

I have a partial view where each I pass the id of a control to another control. However, I do not know how to do this after a partial view has been rendered dynamically. I need some way to figure out the new Id that is assign to each element.

Comment: are you asking two questions? Caching and unique id in the html returned???

Comment: I want to know how setting caching to false assigns unique ID and how I can retrieve these unique ids